# Find the volume of the region bounded by $ (x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})^{2}=x$

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus

I tried to convert it to spherical coordinates to find the bounds:

$(p^{2})^{2} = p\sin(\phi) \cos(\theta)$

=> $ p^{3} = \sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)$

not sure where to go from here..

$ 0 < \theta < 2 \pi $ and $ 0 < \phi < \pi $ as usual?

Which means 0 < p < 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Because $x=(.)^2$ it is nonnegative, hence also $\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)$ is nonnegative, hence not all values of angles are possible.

Comment: so  $0 < \phi < \pi $  AND $-\pi/2 < \theta < \pi/2 $
or $ \pi < \theta $ AND $ \phi < 3\pi/2 $

Comment: @Bob ...and $0\leq p\leq \sqrt[3]{\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)}$.

Comment: Okay, so how I do set up my integration? Split it into two parts based on phi and theta?